How to authenticate in the Keycloak admin api?
So Keycloak has this admin api:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/22.0.1/rest-api/index.html#_overview
They do not mention what kind of authentication to use. I tried with Basic, but it does not work.

Access Token Request
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.3.2
Token Endpoint
POST http://localhost:8080/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token

grant_type: password
username  : {admin username}
password  : {admin password}
client_id : admin-cli

Demo
1 Install Docker Desktop for Windows or Mac
https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/


2 Launch Keycloak by docker-compose
Save as docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15.6
    container_name: postgres_db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

  keycloak_web:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.3
    container_name: keycloak_web
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password

      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: false

      KC_LOG_LEVEL: info
      KC_METRICS_ENABLED: true
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    command: start-dev
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

volumes:
  postgres_data:

docker compose up -d


3 Get master token by Postman
Download and install Postman
POST http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token

In body tab
Select x-www-form-urlencoded
Master's admin credential username is admin, password is admin.
grant_type: password
username: admin
password: admin
client_id: admin-cli


In Tests tab
const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("master-token", jsonData.access_token);


Press Send button

4 Call Admin API by Postman
Get reamls list
GET http://localhost:8080/admin/realms

In Authorization tab,
Select Bearer Token and enter this text in Token editor control
{{master-token}}


You can see the realms list in the response Body

Note
The master token is valid for only 60 seconds as default.
You can extend more time for debugging purposes.
By Browser, open this URL
http://localhost:8080

Login using the master credential
username is "admin" and password is "admin"


Happy to hear you got it.

Look like you know Keycloak. Is it possible to get a token based on another token? I mean client makes a request to resource server with a jwt token it got from kc. RS1 needs to make a request to RS2. Can it get a new token, by using the old token with a different scope from Keycloak?

I am not sure Resource1's token get a new token for Resource 2 but it seems not a correct action. new token can get by refresh token for same resource's token not a different Resource token. I think you want to resource access evaluation. May be this answer help to understand steps.
If is is not looking for, you can make new question in Stack Over flow.

casually dropping better documentation than official keycloak doc!

It's actually well-documented here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#admin-rest-api

Admin REST API
To invoke the API you need to obtain an access token with the appropriate permissions.

Examples of using CURL

Authenticating with a username and password
Authenticating with a service account


Example using Java

Authenticating with keycloak-admin-client library




